# Postfix(admin), Dovecot, MySQL: Aliases not working

Tags: nginx, mysql, debian, postfix, dovecot

I'm able to send mail to the mailboxes i've setup with postfixadmin. This is working correctly and i can send and deliver mail on them. But now i'm in need of Aliases to work properly as well.
I've used a tutorial to set things up listed [here](https://www.crahl.ca/blog/postfixdovecotpostfixadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04/). Yet somehow postfix keeps on trying to send the mail to a mailbox for the alias.

Main email: `name@domain.nl`

Alias email: `alias@domain.nl`

The records in the database are correctly set and when i'm running this command:

`postmap -q alias@domain.nl mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf`

i'm retrieving the right emailaddress: `name@domain.nl` which has a mailbox attached to it.
What am i doing wrong?

The logs don't provide any useful information. When i'm sending a mail to my alias the logs looks like the following:

```
Jun 10 10:38:13 localhost postfix/smtpd[3061]: C27DC614DD: client=mail-wm0-f41.google.com[74.125.82.41]
Jun 10 10:38:13 localhost postfix/cleanup[3072]: C27DC614DD: message-id=<CAGUk6whj3Drb-c=5N55TU80UoKR6sC2r4k+3jtxj9pBO5Gp5Pg@mail.gmail.com>
Jun 10 10:38:13 localhost postfix/qmgr[30229]: C27DC614DD: from=<some.personal.email@gmail.com>, size=2011, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 10 10:38:13 localhost postfix/smtpd[3061]: disconnect from mail-wm0-f41.google.com[74.125.82.41]
Jun 10 10:38:14 localhost postfix/smtp[3074]: C27DC614DD: to=<some.personal.email@gmail.com>, orig_to=<alias@domain.nl>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.27]:25, delay=0.32, delays=0.07/0.01/0.15/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1465547906 q2si2091788wme.1 - gsmtp)
Jun 10 10:38:14 localhost postfix/qmgr[30229]: C27DC614DD: removed
```

Yet it doesn't get into the mailbox of `name@domain.nl`

My `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nl/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nl/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert=yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    permit_mynetworks
    reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination

smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = mail.domain.nl

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $myhostname

mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

disable_vrfy_command = yes
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail

virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf

virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

My `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` looks like this:

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password=spieard123
default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT
password_query = SELECT username as user, password, '/var/mail/%d/%n' as userdb_home, 'maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n' as userdb_mail, 5000 as userdb_uid, 5000 as userdb_gid FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
```

My `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext` looks like this:

```
passdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/%d/%n
}
```

[Chat with NickW.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40988/discussion-between-baklap4-and-nickw)

I've opened up a new room since the one with NickW is frozen. [You can join here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41804/postfixadmin-dovecot-mysql-aliases-not-working)

**Postfixadmin setup:**
[image: Postfix admin]

Comment: Could you put up your main.cf, with anything sensitive redacted of course..

Comment: So, you're using dovecot, how is the dovecot-sql.conf file set up? What does your `password_query` look like?

Comment: @NickW Added it!

Comment: @Baklap4, if the emails are delivered, are they accidentally landing in SPAM or Junk folder? Have you already checked that?

Comment: @bangal Whenever i send a mail to `name@domain.nl` (which is a physical mailbox) it's received correctly. Whenever i send a mail to `alias@domain.nl` (which should redirect the mail to `name@domain.nl`) nothing happens. As seen in the logs it tries to send to a physical mailbox `alias@domain.nl` which does not exist as it's an alias. So no the issue is not Spam/Junk.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're selecting your endpoint from mailbox, not from the virtual users table, so postfix knows where it should go, but not dovecot.

Change :

`SELECT username as user, password, '/var/mail/%d/%n' as userdb_home,       'maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n' as userdb_mail, 5000 as userdb_uid, 5000 as userdb_gid FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'`

To:

`password_query = SELECT email as user, password, '/var/mail/%d/%n' as userdb_home,       'maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n' as userdb_mail, 5000 as userdb_uid, 5000 as userdb_gid FROM virtual_users WHERE email=(SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source = '%u');`

Obviously, the DB and table names may vary.. the `AND active = '1'` shouldn't be necessary since it's not the mailbox table..

Comment: Hmm i've changed the query field names to my needs yet i'm still not getting the email. Any other info you want to see?

Comment: A question, under `/var/mail/domain.nl/` how are the mailboxes named?

Comment: Like this: `drwx--S---  5 vmail vmail 4096 May 10 09:52 name`
Where name can be any mailbox name. The mailbox table has a column named: `maildir` which contains the value `domain.nl/name`

Comment: So they're just the username without the domain? BTW, you did restart dovecot after making that change, right? Also, what does dovecot log when it delivers the mail (or doesn't)?

Comment: yes just the username. And yes i've restarted dovecot multiple times

Comment: What does dovecot log then?

Comment: dovecot log says nothing in particular: 
`Jun 10 12:49:21 master: Info: Dovecot v2.2.13 starting up for imap, pop3, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
Jun 10 12:50:43 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Jun 10 12:50:43 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth/libdriver_mysql.so
Jun 10 12:50:43 auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Jun 10 12:50:43 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40988/discussion-between-baklap4-and-nickw).

Comment: Granted you the +50 for helping too bad we didn't come to a solution.

Comment: Seriously, was anyone able to help you on the postfix list?

Comment: Nopes not really so it's not fixed too bad :/

Comment: That's amazing, we pretty much exhausted all of the possible options.. sorry I couldn't help more :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to check your alias is working properly you can try to check your **MySQL** directly first.

From your log I don't see any attempt delivering to your mailbox

**Select goto from alias**

For alias you should see something like this in your log

```
29 06:46:59 mail postfix/local[15339]: A8967BF907: to=<yourmailbox@domain.com>, orig_to=<youralias@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=1.1, delays=1/0.02/0/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered
```

By looking at your log it looks like it's alias to your gmail address

**Edited**
I read your comment and i simulated the same scenario. If you were to follow your flow, you should be seeing the following in your log.

```
Jun 29 08:15:31 mail postfix/qmgr[9259]: D803DC04BD: from=<someone@gmail.com>, size=741, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Jun 29 08:15:31 mail postfix/smtpd[18918]: disconnect from micro.sg[128.199.136.21] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Jun 29 08:15:31 mail dovecot: lda(someone@domain.com): msgid=<ee6c9f45452e0afa0b7028fccc380362@domain.com>: saved mail to INBOX
Jun 29 08:15:31 mail postfix/pipe[18984]: D803DC04BD: to=<name@domain.com>, orig_to=<alias@domain.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.06, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Jun 29 08:15:33 mail postfix/smtp[18941]: D803DC04BD: to=<your-personal@gmail.com>, orig_to=<alias@domain.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.27]:25, delay=1.4, delays=0.01/0/0.87/0.49, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1467202533 f205si352653oib.152 - gsmtp)
Jun 29 08:15:33 mail postfix/qmgr[9259]: D803DC04BD: removed
```

notice there were 2 different smtp calls and deliveries. Can you please check and make sure your deliver to local mailbox is check in your postfix admin.
[Please see the postfixadmin -> Virtual List -> Mailbox -> Alias screen. You should have deliver to local inbox check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gTrx.png)

If you have checked the above box, then it's a different set of problem.

Comment: My alias is properly working as one can see in the question asked.
`postmap -q alias@domain.nl mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf`
returns the correct email address namely: `name@domain.nl`
As one can see in the chat with NickW my mailbox of `name@domain.nl` is redirected to my personal gmail account.
But since the email from `alias@domain.nl` does not get to `name@domain.nl` it won't get back into my personal gmail inbox.
My email `alias@domain.nl` is an alias for `name@domain.nl`

Comment: So the flow is as following:
1) send mail (from personal gmail account) to `alias@domain.nl`
2) email gets redirected to `name@domain.nl` since `alias@domain.nl` is an alias for `name@domain.nl`
3) Everything send to `name@domain.nl` will be redirected to my personal gmail account.

Comment: And if i had enough reputation i'd vote this answer down as it's a comment and all the info is already provided in the question/chat.

Comment: cool it if your problem is not giving you enough problem already. Note mail.log is a very good place to find out the problem. I've updated on how a alias log should look like if you follow your flow.

Comment: the checkbox you're talking about is when adding a physical mailbox and you want to redirect mail from that physical mailbox towards your personal mail. I don't have this one checked.

I've added an alias for this physical mailbox `(Virtual management -> add alias)`
The log provided in my question is all i've got from the logs. I can add verbose logging but to which do i have to add these? Dovecot logs don't show anything interesting as well.

Comment: U added a alias@domain to name@domain.com and then a alias@domain.com to yourpersonal@gmail.com. So email sent go to alias > name > your gmail account but you not receiving email on your name@domain account right? If not using this method how did you do your redirect from name@domain.com to gmail? Or are you not receiving on gmail? Because your log shows the email to gmail is sent. It's likely end up in your spam or junk if that's the case. I would recommend just create alias@ to both your name@ and gmail account

Comment: If you want to receive both in your name@ and gmail you need to check that box. Else it will only be sent to gmail, and no copy will be saved in name@domain.com

Comment: What i did: 
Create a physical mailbox (`name@domain.nl`)
Created an Alias (by `Virtual management -> add Alias`) which points to `name@domain.nl`
Every mail going to `name@domain.nl` goes to my personal mail.
If i send a mail to `name@domain.nl` i do receive the mail on my personal mail. If i sent a mail to `alias@domain.nl` i don't get anything.

Comment: If u want to direct your mail from name@domain.com to gmail, go to Virtual List > scroll down and find name@domain.com and on the right list of actions you can see alias. If you add gmail there, together with the above mentioned checkbox checked, you will receive on both name and gmail. I've just tried and it's working on my end. This solution means alias > name > gmail and receive both on name and gmail.

Comment: Take a screenshot of your postfix admin screen for your alias and mailbox pls thanks.

Comment: you clearly don't get the question here.
As i said before sending mail to `name@domain.nl` goes straight to my personal mail.

But since this is a mailserver one can add Aliases connected to the physcial mailbox `name@domain.nl` So if one mails to the alias the email will be sent to `name@domain.nl` If my current setup is correctly set up the mail to alias will go to Alias -> Physical mailbox (NOT SAVED) -> personal email (SAVED).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41810/discussion-between-dave-teu-and-baklap4).

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my first reply (below) - it works but it's propably not a good solution.

Is there any chance you got receive_override_options=no_address_mappings in your Postfix main.cf or master.cf.

I had it as -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings for both the SMTP as well as the Submission Port. (I still have it for DSpam).

If you remove it Postfix tells Dovecot which user it should deliver the mail to:

```
userdb { 
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}
```

/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf:

```
user_query = SELECT maildir, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid FROM mailbox, domain WHERE username = '%u' AND mailbox.active = '1' AND domain.domain = '%d' AND domain.active = '1'
```

This way Dovecot can know which accounts really exist (and have mail directories) and Postfix tells Dovecot to which account an address maps.

---

<del>Did you try allow_all_users=yes in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext</del>

```
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail allow_all_users=yes home=/var/mail/%d/%n
}
```

<del>It may be necessary to symlink the aliased users / domains</del>

```
cd /var/mail
ln -s domain.tld alias_domain.tld
or
ln -s domain.tld/user domain2.tld/user_alias
```

<del>which makes it not as elegant as a working userdb SQL lookup for dovecot would be...</del>

```
userdb { 
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}
```

<del>The best I got so far is:</del>

```
user_query = SELECT maildir, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid FROM mailbox, domain WHERE local_part = '%u' AND domain.domain = '%d';
```

<del>(assuming 5000:5000 = vmail:vmail)</del>

<del>which makes at least makes the user_aliases work (I can't manage to get the user aliases to work on alias domains)</del>

<del>Postbox will reject unknown virtual users correctly due to the many SQL Queries provided by Postfixadmin, but the userdb SQL lookup provided for dovecot is missing both the alias and alias_domain tables and I'm not good enough in SQL to fix it.</del>